# What is the Relationship between a Closed Map and a Closed Linear Operator?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

A closed map between topological spaces maps closed sets to closed sets, while a closed linear operator between Banach spaces has a closed graph in the product topology.

Is this just a co-incidental use of the same "closed" terminology or is there some relationship between the two ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Eric Wofsey pointed out, the terms are just coincidence. A closed mapping and a closed linear operator are not equivalent when considering a linear operator between two Banach spaces.

To show that they are unrelated, you might want to do the following exercises, which is Exercise 1.74 in Megginson's *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory*:

- Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and let $T : X \to Y$ be a linear operator that is neither injective nor the zero operator. Find a closed subset $F \subset X$ such that $T(F)$ is not closed in $Y$.
- Find a linear operator $T : X \to Y$ that satisfies the hypotheses of the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem) even though there is a closed subset $F \subset X$ such that $T(F)$ is not closed in the range of $T$.

Comment: I'm thinking about 1.74. Haven't got far yet though.

Comment: For anyone wondering, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4671392/739818) is a solution for the first bullet.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a coincidence.  They are both derived from "closed" in the sense of closed sets, but they are not directly related to each other.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I have spent a couple of hours futilely trying to prove that  a closed linear operator is a closed map, alternatively to find additional conditions in which a linear operator mapping closed sets to closed sets is a "closed linear operator". Now I can proceed with something more productive.