# Closed map from $C^1[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$ and non closed functional on $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X=C^1[0,1]$ and $Y=C[0,1]$, both with the sup norm. Define $F: X \rightarrow Y$ by $F(x)=x+x'$ and $f: X \rightarrow K$ $f(x)=x(1)+x'(1)$ for $x \in X$. (Where $K$ is scalar)

I want to prove the following ''$F$ is closed map but $f$ is not a closed map.''

My attempt:
In order to prove that $F$ is closed map first i will show that $F^{-1} : \text{range } F \rightarrow X$ exist and then $F^{-1} $ is bounded. Let $F(x)=F
(y) \implies x+x' = y+y' \implies x-y = -x' + y' \implies (x-y)=-(x-y)'$. why it imply $F$ is one one? I stuck here how to proceed further?
Is my approach right?

In order to show $f$ is not closed. I have to find a closed set in $X$ whose image under $f$ is not closed in $K$. I don't have any intuition how to think such set.

Note : Here $x \in X$ so consider $x$ as a function. Really sorry for bad notations

Comment: How is $f$ defined?

Comment: thanks. i edited

Comment: By $x(1)$ and $x'(1)$, do you mean the constant maps $(y \mapsto x(1)) \in C[0, 1]$ and $(y \mapsto x'(1)) \in C[0, 1]$?

Comment: x is a function because x bleongs to X

Comment: I know. $x \in C^1[0, 1]$ right? So $f(x) = x(1) + x'(1)$ is just a real number not a function in $Y = C[0, 1]$

Comment: Sorry . $f$ is functional here

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892303/27978 In particular, the fact that $f$ is not zero and has a non trivial kernel is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer For the first part: In the context of Functional Analysis a closed linear map is one whose graph is closed. [This is not equivalent to  the topological definition  of a map which sends closed sets to closed sets].
Suppose $(x_n, F(x_n))$ is a sequence in the graph of $F$ converging to $(x,y)$.  Then $x_n \to x$ uniformly and  $x_n+x_n' \to y$ uniformly.  But then $x_n' \to y-x$ uniformly. This implies that $y-x=x'$ so $y+x' =F(x)$. This proves the first part.

Second part: For the second part: Let $x_n(t)=\frac {t^{n}} n$. Then $(x_n, f(x_n)) \to (0,1)$ and $(0,1)$ does not belong to the graph of $f$.

Comment: For second part , we know that $C^1[0,1]$ is not a banach space under sup norm. Can i apply closed graph theorem here?

Comment: You are right. I have edited my answer. @Smarty

Answer (score 1):

To complement Kavi's answer, here is the topological version:

Let $C = \{ x_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $x_n(t)= n e^{-t} + {1 \over n} (1-e^{-t})$. Each pair of distinct elements of $C$ are separated by at least one, hence $C$ is closed. Note that $F(x_n) = f(x_n) = {1 \over n}$, but $0 \notin F(C)$ and so neither $F$ nor $f$ is a closed map in the topological sense.

The key here is that the kernel and range are non trivial.

Comment: How you thought such sequence? is it any special sequence

Comment: It is a particular example from a fairly general idea in a proof, see the last line on the answer above.

Comment: See the link in the comment to your question.

Comment: If kernel and image are non trivial for a linear operator between two normed spaces then can we always find a closed set in domain whose image is not closed

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}{}$