# A linear transformation is open map if and only if surjective and closed map if and only if injective

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, open-map, closed-map

Q.If $d$ and $e$ are positive integer and $T:R^{d} → R^{e}$ be a linear transformation then

(a) $T$ is open map if and only if $T$ is surjective

(b) $T$ is closed map if and only if $T$ is either zero or injective

Here is an argument .

For (a)

Suppose $T$ is an open map. We want to show that $T$ is surjective. To do this, suppose that $T$ is not surjective. Then, there exists some vector $y$ in $R^{e}$ such that there is no $x$ in $R^{d}$ such that $T(x) = y$. Consider the set $U = {y}^c$, the complement of ${y}$ in $R^{e}$.
Since $T$ is not surjective, $U$ is non-empty. Now, note that $T(U)$ is an open set in $R^{e}$, since $T$ is an open map. This follows from the fact that $T(U)$ is the image of an open set under a continuous linear transformation. But, since $y$ is not in $U$, we have that $y$ is not in $T(U)$. Thus, $T(U)$ is a non-empty open subset of $R^{e}$ that does not contain $y$. This contradicts the fact that $y$ is in the closure of $T(U)$ (since every non-empty open set contains a point in its closure). Therefore, we must have that T is surjective.

Suppose $T$ is surjective. We want to show that $T$ is an open map. To do this, let $U$ be an open set in $R^{d}$. We want to show that $T(U)$ is an open set in $R^{e}$. Let $y$ be a point in $T(U)$, so that there exists some $x$ in $U$ such that $T(x) = y$. Since $U$ is open, there exists some $r > 0$ such that the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$, $B(x, r)$, is contained in $U$. Now, consider the image of $B(x, r)$ under $T$. We have that:

$T(B(x, r)) = {T(x + h) : ||h|| < r}
= {T(x) + T(h) : ||h|| < r}
= {y + T(h) : ||h|| < r}$

Note that this last set is the translation of the open ball centered at $y$ with radius $r$, $B(y, r)$, by the vector $T(h)$, which varies over all vectors of norm less than $r$. Since $T$ is surjective, we have that for any $z$ in $R^{e}$, there exists some $x$ in $R^{d}$ such that $T(x) = z$. Therefore, for any point $w$ in $B(y, r)$, there exists some $h$ in $R^{d}$ such that $T(h) = w - y$. Thus, we can write:

$w = y + T(h) = T(x) + T(h) = T(x + h)$

Since $x + h$ is in $B(x, r)$, we have that $w$ is in $T(B(x, r))$. This shows that $B(y, r)$ is a subset of $T(B(x, r))$. But, since $T$ is a linear transformation, it is continuous. Therefore, $T(B(x, r))$ is an open set in $R^{e}$. Thus, we have shown that for any point $y$ in $T(U)$, there exists an open ball around $y$ that is contained in $T(U)$. This shows that $T(U)$ is an open set in $R^{e}$, and thus, $T$ is an open map.

For (b)

Suppose $T$ is a closed map. We want to show that $T$ is either zero or injective.

$Case   1$ : $T$ is the zero map. In this case, $T$ is clearly a closed map, and $T$ is also injective.

$Case   2$: $T$ is not the zero map.

In this case, there exists some nonzero vector $x$ in $R^{d}$ such that $T(x)$ is nonzero. Since $T$ is not the zero map, there exists some vector $y$ in $R^{d}$ such that $T(y)$ is nonzero. Since $T$ is closed, we have that whenever a sequence ${x_n}$ in $R^{d}$ converges to some limit $x$ in $R^{d}$, the sequence ${T(x_n)}$ converges to some limit $y$ in $R^{e}$.
Now, consider the sequence ${x + (1/n)y}$ in $R^{d}$. This sequence converges to $x$, but ${T(x + (1/n)y)} = {T(x) + (1/n)T(y)}$ does not converge to $T(x)$ as $n$ goes to $∞$, since $T(y)$ is nonzero. Therefore, we have a sequence in $R^{d}$ that converges to $x$, but whose image under $T$ does not converge to $T(x)$. This implies that $T$ is not a closed map. Therefore, we must have that $T$ is injective.

Suppose $T$ is either zero or injective. We want to show that $T$ is a closed map.

$Case 1$: $T$ is the zero map. In this case, $T$ is clearly a closed map.

$Case 2$: $T$ is injective. Let ${x_n}$ be a sequence in $R^{d}$ that converges to some limit $x$ in $R^{d}$, and let ${T(x_n)}$ be the corresponding sequence in $R^{e}$. We want to show that ${T(x_n)}$ converges to some limit $y$ in $R^{e}$. Since $T$ is injective, we know that $T(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $R^{e}$. Therefore, there exists some limit $y$ in $R^{e}$ such that ${T(x_n)}$ converges to $y$. Now, we need to show that $y = T(x)$. Since $T$ is injective, we have that $T(x_n) = T(x)$ if and only if $x_n = x$. Therefore, if we assume that $T(x_n)$ converges to $y$, then we must have that $x_n$ converges to $x$. Therefore, we have shown that ${T(x_n)}$ converges to $T(x)$ if and only if ${x_n}$ converges to $x$. Since ${x_n}$ converges to $x$ by assumption, we have that ${T(x_n)}$ converges to $T(x)$. Therefore, $T$ is a closed map.

I didn't find this question in stack, here is my argument Please  have a look.
Thank you

Comment: 1) A bounded linear map between two Banach spaces open if surjective.For converse use the hint: if a linear subspace of a NLS contain a ball, then it would be whole space.

Comment: The sequence $T(x)+(1/n)T(y)$ tends to $T(x)$.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Applying the Banach open mapping theorem for finite dimensional space is an overkill in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument can be substantially simplified.

Concerning (a), If $T$ is open then $T(\{x\,:\,\|x\|<1\})$ contains a ball $\{y\,:\,\|y\|<r\},$ for some $r>0.$ By homogeneity of $T$ we get $\mathbb{R}^e\subset {\rm Im}\,T.$

For the converse direction, by homogeneity and additivity is suffices to show that $T(B_X(0,1))$ contains a ball $B_Y(0,r)$ for some $r>0.$ Let $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_e$ be a linear basis of $\mathbb{R}^e.$ There exist $u_1,u_2,\ldots, u_e\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $T(u_e)=v_e.$ There is $t>0$ such that $t\|u_i\|<1$ for all $1\le i\le e.$ Then
$B_X(0,1)$ contains all vectors of the form $a_1u_1+\ldots +a_eu_e,$ where $|a_1|+\ldots +|a_e|<t.$ Hence  contains all vectors $$T(B_X(0,1))\supset\{a_1v_1+\ldots +a_ev_e\,:\, \quad |a_1|+\ldots +|a_e|<t\}\quad (*)$$ It is not specified what norm OP meant in $\mathbb{R}^e.$ Since all norms are equivalent,  the property of a set being open is independent of the norm. Define the norm on $\mathbb{R}^e$ by
$$\|a_1v_1+\ldots +a_ev_e\|=|a_1|+\ldots +|a_e|$$
By $(*)$ we get $T(B_X(0,1))\supset B_Y(0,t).$

Concerning (b), the range of $T$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d.$ If
$T$ is injective then $T$ is a linear homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^d$ onto ${\rm Im }\,T$, as every invertible linear mapping is a homeomorphism. In particular $T$ is closed from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to ${\rm Im}T,$ and hence to $\mathbb{R}^e$, as ${\rm Im}T$ is a closed subspace.

Assume  $T$ is nonzero and not injective.  Thus there exists $u\notin \ker T$ and   $0\neq v\in \ker T.$ Consider the set $$C=\{ tv+(\arctan t)u\,:\, t\in \mathbb{R}\}$$ The set $C$ is closed in the linear span of $u$ and $v,$ hence $C$ is closed. On the other hand $T(C)=\{\alpha Tu\,:\, -{\pi\over 2}<\alpha <{\pi \over 2}\},$ hence it is not closed.

Comment: For (a), I think you have only shown $T$ is open implies $T$ is surjective, not the converse.

Comment: @liyiontheway Thanks a lot for spotting that, shame on me !!! I will re-edit. The only excuse is that the date of my answer is just one day after April Fools' Day. By the way the proof in OP is incorrect. The author does not make use of  finite dimension of the spaces. The proof of this theorem (due to Banach) for infinite dimensional spaces is highly nontrivial.

Comment: Haha, everybody makes mistakes. In fact I am learning functional analysis, and I'm trying to get some intuition of the open mapping theorem in the finite dimensional case.