Why $A(E)$ is open relative to $Y$ if $E$ is open?
Suppose $A$ is a linear transformation of $R^n$ into $R^m$. Let $Y=\{ Ax:x\in R^n \}$. I need to prove $A(E)$ is open relative to $Y$ for every open set $E \subset R^n$.
My try is as follows:
For every $y_0 \in A(E)$, there exists $x_0 \in E$ such that $Ax_0=y_0$. Since $E$ is open, we can find $r>0$ so that $|x-x_0|<r \implies x\in E$.
Put $Ax=y$, it follows that $$|y-y_0|=|A(x-x_0)| \le \|A\||x-x_0| < \|A\|r$$
where $\|A\|$ is the norm of $A$.
But I can't figure out how to show $|p-y_0|<\|A\|r \implies p \in A(E)$.
Update My attempt of proof：
Case 1: $Rank(A)=0$
$Y=\{0\}$, $\{0\}$ is open relative to $\{0\}$.
Case 2: $Rank(A)=L>0$
Let $\{y_1, \cdots, y_L\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $Y$, then for each $y_k$, there exists $x_k \in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax_k=y_k, (1 \le k \le L)$.
Put $M=\max_{1 \le k \le L}|x_k|$, pick $\delta < \frac{r}{L M}$, then we have $$V=\bigg\{x_0+\sum_{k=1}^Lc_kx_k:|c_k|<\delta, 1\le k \le L \bigg\} \subset N_r(x_0) \subset E, $$
since $|\sum_{k=1}^Lc_kx_k|\le \sum_{k=1}^L|c_k||x_k| \le \sum_{k=1}^L\delta M=L\delta M<r$. It follows that $$A(V) =\bigg\{y_0+\sum_{k=1}^Lc_k y_k:|c_k|<\delta, 1\le k \le L \bigg\} \subset A(E).$$
For every $y\in Y$ such that $|y-y_0|<\delta$, there exists $c_k$ such that
$y-y_0=\sum_{k=1}^Lc_ky_k .$
Since $|y-y_0|=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^L|c_k|^2}<\delta \implies |c_k|<\delta, 1 \le k \le L$, we see $y \in A(E)$.
Thus $N_{\delta}(y_0) \subset A(E).$
Is my proof correct, or miss something ?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4671269/701541 Does this help?

Actually the last statement is false - $|A|$ is too big. Consider $m=n=2$, $A = diag(1, 1/2)$ and $E$ the unit ball, then $p = (0,3/4)$ is not in $A(E)$ despite $|p| < |A|1 = 1$. What does work is $1/|B|$ where $B : R^m \to R^n$ satisfies $ABA = A$.

Put another way, $|A|$ is the largest singular value of $A$, so if $E$ is the unit ball then $A(E)$ is contained in the ball of radius $|A|$. But you want a ball that is inside $A(E)$, and a radius that works is the smallest (positive) singular value.

I shall expand on my comments on the question.
What we need is a value $\lambda > 0$ such that for all $y \in Y$, there is some $x \in X$ with $y = Ax$ and $\lambda|x| \le |y|$. (That is, the image $\{Ax \mid x \in R^n, |x| < 1\}$ of the unit ball contains the relative ball $\{y \in Y \mid |y| < \lambda\}$.) Given such a $\lambda$, you can show that if $y \in Y$ and $|y - Ax_0| < \lambda r$, there exists $x$ such that $y = Ax$ with $|x - x_0| < r$.
Suppose we have a linear map $B \colon R^m \to R^n$ such that $ABy = y$ for all $y \in Y$. Choose $\lambda > 0$ such that $\lambda \|B\| \le 1$. (If $B = 0$ then $Y = \{0\}$ and $\lambda$ may be arbitrary; if $B \ne 0$ you may let $\lambda = 1/\|B\|$.) Then if $y \in Y$, taking $x = By$ gives $$\lambda |x| = \lambda |By| \le \lambda \|B\| |y| \le |y|.$$
We could use the pseudoinverse, but we don't need something that strong. Instead, pick a basis $\{b_1, \ldots, b_m\}$ of $R^m$ such that $\{b_1, \ldots, b_k\}$ is a basis of $Y$. For $i \le k$, since $b_i$ is in the image of $A$, choose $a_i$ such that $Aa_i = b_i$. Then there is a (unique) linear map $B \colon R^m \to R^n$ such that $B(b_i) = a_i$ for $i \le k$ and $B(b_i) = 0$ for $i > k$ (actually the zero is arbitrary here). You should be able to show that $ABy = y$ for any $y \in Y$, so we are done.

P.S.  Another way to use $ABy = y \;(y \in Y)$ to prove that $A(E)$ is relatively open: Show that $A(E) = B^{-1}(E) \cap Y$, and note that $B^{-1}(E)$ is open because $B$ is continuous.

Thanks a lot for your help! I have updated my question. Could you please review my new attempt ?
