# Non-trivial closed maps on Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let's call a map closed if it takes any closed subset to a closed subset.

I'm wondering if there are some "standard" examples of closed (in this sense) linear maps on a Banach space, other than the zero map or a linear homeomorphism. More precisely:

**Question:** What is an example of a bounded linear map $T\colon X\to X$, where $X$ is a Banach space, that takes closed sets to closed sets, other than $T=0$ or a homeomorphism?

Comment: Just to clarify for readers: This definition of closed is distinct from the property of having a closed graph [(in which case, the answer would be "all")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem#In_functional_analysis), which is often also called "closed."

Comment: Such an operator must be injective (see [Ex. 1.74](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892303/739818) in Megginson's book).
So such an operator is an isomorphism onto its image.

Comment: Just take the shift map in $\ell_p$, appending zero to each sequence.

Comment: The projection $p:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ on one of the coordinates maps the graph of the hyperbola $y=1/x$ (which is a closed set) to $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ which is not closed.  If you have any linear map that maps a $2$-dimensional subspace onto a $1$-dimensional subspace, there is a hyperbola like this in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was noted in the comments (and easy to see), a nonzero closed linear map of Banach spaces is necessarily injective. Hence, if $T: X\to X$ is a closed bounded nonzero linear operator, then the image of $T$ is a closed subspace $Y$ of $X$ and $T: X\to Y$ is a bounded invertible map. Conversely, if $T: X\to X$ is a bounded injective linear map with closed image, then $T$ is a closed map. There are easy examples of such maps. For instance, take $X=\ell_p, 1\le p\le\infty$, and let
$$
T: (x_1, x_2,...)\mapsto (0, x_1, x_2, ...)
$$
be the shift map. Then $T$ is a closed bounded injective (but not surjective) map.